# Cómo comprobar que pudo obtener la imagen

Tags: javascript, ajax

Necesito comprobar si se pudo acceder a la imagen, esto, solo para comprobar acceso a internet. Este ejemplo no logra obtener el true o false y así poder comprobar conexión ¿Qué hace falta?

```js
$.ajax({

url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/ZAl1gIwyUsvfwxoW9ns47iJFioHXODBbIkrK',

type: 'get',

success: function(true) {

alert("Online");

}

});
```

Comment: Quizás el [onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) te sirva más para lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Para revisar si una imagen o página se puede acceder, no necesitas descargarla (métodos GET/POST), solo consultar si está disponible (método HEAD), sin embargo, algunos sitios evitan [peticiones de origen cruzado (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) y solo necesitas buscar algún recurso no tenga esa restricción, de preferencia, una página o imagen dentro de tu sitio.

También necesitas agregar una función para saber que no se puede acceder.

Finalmente, el resultado de esto no es 100% confiable, porque no solo dependes de tu conexión a Internet, sino también de la disponibilidad del sitio a verificar.

**Nota:** Las peticiones GET y HEAD, generalmente son guardadas en caché, pero se puede evitar agregando una marca de tiempo (timestamp), solo hay que tener cuidado en que la URL a consultar no incluya parámetros (`?`):

```js
// Lo puse en función para poder probar varias URL
function isOnline(url) {
    $.ajax({
        // Agregar timestamp para evitar caché
        url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
        // Consultar solo encabezados, no descargar página o imagen
        method: 'HEAD',
        success: function() {
            console.log('Online', url);
        },
        // Saber que no se pudo conectar
        error: function() {
            console.log('Offline', url);
        }
    });
}
// Es probable que estas peticiones sean bloqueadas por CORS
isOnline('https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/ZAl1gIwyUsvfwxoW9ns47iJFioHXODBbIkrK');
isOnline('https://www.google.com');
// Intenta con una dirección que no tenga restricciones
isOnline('https://reqres.in/api/products/3');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aún después de desconectar el internet sigue apareciendo como conectado

Comment: @NuevoUsuario, actualicé la respuesta, agregando un parámetro en la URL para evitar que se guarde en caché.